# How to obtain the sum of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}(3n+1)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

How to prove what follows?

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}(3n+1)}=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}}{3}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{2^{\frac{2}{3}}+2^{\frac{1}{3}}+1}}{2^{\frac{1}{3}}-1}\right)+\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{2^{\frac{2}{3}}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{2^{\frac{1}{3}}\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}$$

My attempt:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n(3n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{2^n(3n+1)}|_{x=1}$$
We put $$S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{2^n(3n+1)}\implies S^{'}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{3n}}{2^n(3n+1)}$$
$$S^{'}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{x^3}{2})^n}{3n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^3}{2})^n(1-\frac{3n}{3n+1})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^3}{2})^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^3}{2})^n\frac{3n}{3n+1}=\frac{1}{2-\frac{x^3}{2}}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^3}{2})^n(\frac{3n}{3n+1})=\alpha-\beta$$
Where
$$\beta=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{x^3}{2})^n(\frac{3n}{3n+1})$$
So $$\beta=?$$

Waiting for your help to find a beta or prove equal above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your attempt a little bit to get an easier way of solving this problem:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{2^n(3n+1)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{2})^{3n}(3n+1)} = \sqrt[3]{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{2})^{3n+1}(3n+1)}$$
And now you can find the value of $$S(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{3n+1}}{3n+1}$$ and replace $x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ back into $S(x)$

Comment: Yes, I solved it the way you mentioned and I finished proving it. Really, I got tired. Thank you, sir, for your idea.@Dao Minh Dung

Comment: @Bachamohamed you're welcome. If you don't mind, can you mark my answer as the accepted one?

Comment: Yes, a voice on that is acceptable

Answer (score 13):

**Hint**. One may prove that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}(3n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1\frac{x^{3n}}{2^{n}}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^3}{2}\right)^{n}dx=\int_0^1\frac{2}{2-x^3}\:dx
$$
Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{3n+1}\implies f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{3n+1}$$ and
$$3xf'(x)+f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3n+1}{3n+1}x^n=\frac1{1-x}.$$

The solution of the homogeneous part of this linear ODE is
$$f_h(x)=\frac c{\sqrt[3]x},$$

and by variation of the constant

$$f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt[3]x}\left(\int\frac{\sqrt[3]x}{1-x}dx+c\right).$$

Answer (score 5):

For all $|x|<1$ we have the elementary geometric series $$\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x} \\\underbrace{=}^{x\to x/2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{2^n} =\frac{2}{2-x}$$ now replacing $x$ by $x^3$ and then on integration from $0$ to $1$ we have $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^n(3n+1)}=\int_0^1\frac{2}{2-x^3}dx$$ since $x^3-2=(x-\sqrt[3]2)(x^2-\sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{8})$ by partial fraction of the integrand we write the  last expression as $$-\int_0^1\frac{2}{x^3-2} dx=-\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]4}\int_0^1\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{x-\sqrt[3]{2}}}-\color{blue}{\frac{x+\sqrt[3]{16}}{x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}x +\sqrt[3]4}}\right)dx$$ It's is easy to see  that red integral $$\int_0^1\color{red}{\frac{1}{x-\sqrt[3]2}}dx =\ln(|x- \sqrt[3]2|)\bigg|_0^1=\ln(|1-\sqrt[3]2|)-\ln\sqrt[3]2\cdots(1)$$
Further note that $$\int_0^1\color{blue}{\frac{x+\sqrt[3]{16}}{x^2+\sqrt[3]{2}x+\sqrt[3]{4}}}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left(\frac{2x+\sqrt[3]2}{x^2+\sqrt[3]2 x+\sqrt[3]4}+\frac{3\cdot 
\sqrt[3]{2}}{x^2+\sqrt[3]2x+\sqrt[4]{4}}\right)dx$$ The last two integral are standard and elementary logarithm and arctangent integrals and integrating them we have $$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+\sqrt[3]2x+\sqrt[3]4)+\sqrt[3]{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}x+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)\bigg|_0^1=\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4})-\ln(\sqrt[3]{4})}{2}+\sqrt{3}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\cdots(2)$$ subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$ and multiply by the factor $-\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{2}}$ and simplification gives us the desired result of the series.

> $$\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{4}}\left(\sqrt{3}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}+1}{\sqrt 3}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4})-\ln|\sqrt[3]{2}-1| -\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)\approx 1.18143\cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2^{n}\pars{3n + 1}}} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2^{1/3}}^{3n}\pars{3n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2^{1/3}}^{n}\pars{n + 1}}
\,{1 + \expo{2n\pi\ic/3} + \expo{-2n\pi\ic/3} \over 3}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2^{1/3} \over 3}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{2^{-1/3}}^{n} \over n}
\,\pars{1 + \expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\expo{2n\pi\ic/3} + \expo{2\pi\ic/3}\expo{-2n\pi\ic/3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2^{1/3} \over 3}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{2^{-1/3}}^{n} \over n} +
{2^{4/3} \over 3}\,\Re\bracks{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\pars{2^{-1/3}\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}^{n} \over n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{2^{1/3} \over 3}\,\ln\pars{1 - 2^{-1/3}} -
{2^{4/3} \over 3}\Re\bracks{\expo{-2\pi\ic/3}
\ln\pars{1 - 2^{-1/3}\expo{2\pi\ic/3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{2^{1/3} \over 3}\,\ln\pars{1 - 2^{-1/3}}
\\[1mm] &\ -
{2^{4/3} \over 3}\Re\bracks{\pars{-\,{1 \over 2} - {\root{3} \over 2}\,\ic}
\ln\pars{1 + 2^{-4/3} - 2^{-4/3}\root{3}\ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{2^{1/3} \over 3}\,\ln\pars{1 - 2^{-1/3}}
\\[1mm] &\
-\,{2^{4/3} \over 3}\left[%
-\,{1 \over 2}\ln\pars{\root{(1 + 2^{-4/3})^{2} + (-2^{-4/3}\root{3})^{2}}}\right.
\\[1mm] &\ \phantom{-\,{2^{4/3} \over 3}\left[\right.\,\,\,}+
\left.{\root{3} \over 2}\arctan\pars{-2^{-4/3}\root{3} \over
1 + 2^{-4/3}}\right]
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{-\,{2^{1/3} \over 3}\,\ln\pars{1 - 2^{-1/3}}}
\\[1mm] &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{+ {2^{-2/3} \over 3}\,\ln\pars{1 + 2^{-2/3} + 2^{-1/3}}
+
{2^{1/3}\root{3} \over 3}\arctan\pars{2^{-4/3}\root{3} \over 1 + 2^{-4/3}}}
\\[5mm] &\ \approx 1.1814
\end{align}